# How does mass affect velocity of a skateboard?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, mass

Earlier today, I noticed my little brother playing with his skateboard. He had the strange idea of attaching it to his electric toy car so that he could be dragged by the car using the remote. When I came, he said I was too heavy and it probably wouldn't work. I found it weird as I thought this logic would probably be correct if the skateboard didn't have wheels, as the friction would be greater, but I don't see how added mass would make the skateboard slower with the same force. In this case friction is necessary for the skateboard to move. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does a skateboard not have wheels? I am also in doubt about the sentence "*In this case friction is necessary for the skateboard to move.*" Would you mind elaborating a bit on that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have read your question three time, I still don't get what exactly it is you are asking.

Comment: how does the mass on a skateboard affect its velocity when pulled by the same force?

Comment: @Steeven It took me like 2 reads; but he seems to be considering the fact that the friction between a tire and the ground doesn't resist the motion of the skateboard.  So by increasing the weight, you would not be directly increasing resistance to motion at the tires.  In fact, the additional weight should increase the static frictional force, making it less likely to slip.  If there were not tires, and instead the board were sliding, then increasing weight very obviously increases resistance.

Comment: @JMac: I agree; I've made an edit to make that point more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Well this comes directly from Newton's second Law which states that the rate of change of momentum of an object is proportional to the force applied. Or put into maths:$$F=m\frac{dv}{dt}=ma$$where $F$ is the force applied, m is the mass and $\frac{dv}{dt}$ or more simply put, $a$, is the acceleration.

Another way of looking at it is by the Kinetic energy. The electric toy car has an output energy, $E$ which it will then turn into Kinetic Energy, $KE$. The equation for kinetic energy is $$KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$From this you can see that mass is a factor in how much kinetic energy an object will have, and therefore requires. This equation can be proved as follows.

One equation of motion given by Newton is $$v^2=u^2+2as$$Putting in a value of $u$ (initial speed) as $0$ we can rearrange this to get that the acceleration, $a$ is given by $$a=\frac{v^2}{2s}$$As mentioned before $F=ma$ so we can say that the force is given by:$$F=m\frac{v^2}{2s}$$ As the work done on an object is equal to $Fs$ or force$\times$distance we can say that $$\mathrm{work\ done}=m\frac{v^2}{2}$$As the work done is equal to the kinetic energy we can see that this shows $$KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, mass does **not** affect velocity. Moving with 100 km/hr has got nothing to do with the object being 1 kg or 100 kg.

But the mass **does** affect **acceleration**! This is Newtons' 2nd law:

$$\sum F=ma$$

The sum of all forces $\sum F$ that act on the object **causes** the acceleration $a$ while the mass $m$ **resists** it. Mass is so to speak a "resistance against changes in motion". But not a resistance against motion itself.

So, when many forces act and try to speed up (positive acceleration) - such as a pushing force - or slow down (negative acceleration) - such as kinetic friction - the object, then the mass reduces these force's influence. In other words, it does not help speed up nor help slow down; it *resists* both events. So mass is really not about what the velocity actually is, it just doesn't want it to change.

Now, some forces actually depend on mass as well. This is a separate issue. Kinetic friction e.g., which you would have if the skateboard slides (no wheels), is a force that can depend on mass, and smaller mass thus reduces friction. This also does not influence speed itself but only the change in speed, but reducing the mass can thus do a change in both $m$ and in $\sum F$ in the equation, and so the outcome an be a bit unexpected.

Just keep this in mind, but also note that not many forces can depend on mass (I can only think of static and kinetic friction as of now).